# Java Return Double from SQL Exception (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, exception

Any idea how to handle the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException? How this exception will be appear? Is that because of the return is null?

Below is a screenshot showed how i get an error from my code.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting a `null`?

Comment: hmm, String.valueOf() returns a string. Even String.valueOf((Object)null) returns "null" not null. Unless the object overrides toString to do something funny, I'm not sure comparing to null is what you want.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, yes, i got null on the value. If the value are not null, the exception will not throw. Do you have any idea on this? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

try breaking out the statements, it will be easier to track down the null, also you probably want to check the Double for null and not the String of the Double.

```
String colName=col.getColnmnname();
Double dv = sqlRow.getDoubleValue(colName);

if(dv!=null)
{
    ...
```

edit-maybe like this:

```
if(sqlRow!=null)
{
    try
    {
        String colName=col.getColumnname();
        Double dv = sqlRow.getDoubleValue(colName);
        if(dv!=null)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        //handle the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr Greg, I tried your solution, it is work when the colValue is not null but is not work when the colValue is null. Any advice can give it to me how to handle this 2 different scenario?

Comment: ya, at the end i use catch exception to solve my problem.. do not know is this a right practise or not. Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know of to handle this condition (using a primitive column type and a JDBC ResultSet) is with the [wasNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) method on `ResultSet`.

```
public static Double readDoubleValue(ResultSet rs, String columnName) {
  try {
    Double val = rs.getDouble(columnName);
    if (! rs.wasNull()) {
      return val;
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: ya, at the end i use catch exception to solve my problem.. do not know is this a right practise or not. Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you get column name was double type? if you confirmed. i think you can restart eclipse.may be  you could resolve the question.

Comment: He has a check right above to ensure that `col` is a double type. Additionally, it is highly unlikely that his IDE is causing a runtime error.

Comment: Hi Mr PoWen, i think it should not because of restart eclipse will be solve, anyway i also tried. My problem is when retrieve double as null value and i declare it as null, then exception will be throw.. but if it is not null value, then it be fine. Do you have any idea how to handle my case when i declare the data type as double and the value is null then can be handle by another way instead of hit by the exception? thank you

Comment: i know.i also tried.it works when we wrote code like this: Double d =null;String.valueOf(d);so,i think the problem is "col.getColumnName()",can you show value ? debug this code.output this value ,i think you can get answers. firstly,String.valueOf() method could run when param is null. may be you have to change your method,because the param is invalid.if you tried and failed. tell me and i will be think.

Comment: i used catch exception to solve my problem, because no matter how i tried to do, it was not work until i used catch exception. Anyway, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: are you working or studying? may be we can communication with java. of course,when i get more free time.

Comment: @PoWen yup, you are welcome to chat with me about java... i'm also in the learning stage... hope from the communication we can grow up together... cheers..